# Need assistance on postgresql roles

Tags: postgresql

I have created a readonly role under a DB and granted "select" to those roles on all tables- but how do I check for that roles what permissions are mapped and all the tables mapped to that role for select?

Can some one help Me with the queries.

Need your help..I tried few queries unable to get it.

Comment: login as your user and try to insert or update

Comment: Please edit to show your work. Right now, this is just a requirement with no specific work of your own. Also note that this isn't really a programming question - it's a database configuration question.

Comment: --below is what have executed it lists only 7 tables but there are 53 tables exists
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type FROM information_schema.table_privileges WHERE grantee = 'rolename';

Comment: @user2599851 you need to *edit your question* - it's very difficult to read code/queries/etc as unformatted comments. Also, you need to explain what the issue is.

Comment: Iam new here and will improve on that part..!!

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review the Help section: [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query as a basis for checking the permissions granted on tables to roles:

```
SELECT table_schema,
       table_name, grantee,
       array_agg(privilege_type ORDER BY privilege_type) AS privileges
  FROM information_schema.role_table_grants
  WHERE grantee = 'readonly_role'
  GROUP BY table_schema, table_name, grantee
  ORDER BY table_schema, table_name, grantee;
```

Replace `readonly_role` with the role name of interest. While `grantee` in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses is unnecessary in this specific example, I've included it so that when the `WHERE` clause is modified to change criteria the output will still be grouped and ordered consistently.

Comment: Thank you John,that makes clear to Me and its worked.